# Set page orientation to landscape using ps2pdf

Tags: pdf, orientation, landscape

Is it possible to set page orientation to landscape using ps2pdf on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Setting page orientation](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/cvs/Ps2pdf.htm#Orientation), where this rather convoluted text seems to say that this is impossible:

> By default Ghostscript determines
>   viewing page orientation based on the
>   dominant text orientation on the page.
>   Sometimes, when the page has text in
>   several orientations or has no text at
>   all, wrong orientation can be
>   selected.
>
> Acrobat Distiller parameter
>   AutoRotatePages controls the automatic
>   orientation selection algorithm. On
>   Ghostscript, besides input stream,
>   Distiller parameters can be given as
>   command line arguments. For instance:
>   -dAutoRotatePages=/None or /All or /PageByPage.
>
> When there is no text on the page or
>   automatic page rotation is set to
>   /None an orientation value from
>   setpagedevice is used. Valid values
>   are: 0 (portrait), 3 (landscape), 2
>   (upside down), and 1 (seascape). The
>   orientation can be set from the
>   command line as -c "<>
>   setpagedevice" using Ghostscript
>   directly **but cannot be set in ps2pdf**.
>   See Limitations below.
>
> Ghostscript passes the orientation
>   values from DSC comments to pdfwrite
>   driver **but they are effectively ignored there**. This appears to be
>   consistent with Distiller 5 behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`ps2pdf` is a rather limited utility. It is merely a small batch file (on Unix/Linux: a shell script) which constructs and calls the rather complex Ghostscript commandline while itself using a very simple commandline syntax.

If you need the full power of Ghostscript, you'd be better off calling gswin32c.exe directly.

OK, here is how to rotate pages with Ghostscript. However, this may not work for your intentions, because you cannot **force** a certain orientation for an individual page only. It relies on an internal Ghostscript algorithm that tries to rotate pages automatically, depending on the flow of text inside the PDFs:
* `-dAutoRotatePages=/None`  -- retains orientation of each page;
* `-dAutoRotatePages=/All`  -- rotates all pages (or none) depending on a kind of "majority decision";
* `-dAutoRotatePages=/PageByPage` -- auto-rotates pages individually.

Add one of these to the Ghostscript commandline you're using.

If there is ***no*** text on a page (or if there is an automatic page rotation set to `/None`), then Ghostscript uses the `setpagedevice` settings. You can pass such `setpagedevice` parameters on the Ghostscript commandline using the `-c` switch like this:
* `-c "<</Orientation 3>> setpagedevice"` -- sets *landscape* orientation;
* `-c "<</Orientation 0>> setpagedevice"` -- sets *portrait* orientation;
* `-c "<</Orientation 2>> setpagedevice"` -- sets *upside down* orientation;
* `-c "<</Orientation 1>> setpagedevice"` -- sets *seascape* orientation.

Do you ***require*** usage of `pstopdf` or Ghostscript? Would it be acceptable to use another Free, Open Source Software tool running on the commandline, such as `pdftk.exe`?

In any case, I'd recommend to look at `pdftk` too (which is also available for Windows). It is a commandline tool that can rotate pages from PDFs, and much more. Easier to use than Ghostscript for your stated purpose, and much faster as well. Especially, it can rotate individual pages inside a PDF document, leaving the other pages untouched. See here for details: http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/ .